# How to create an action from history in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-action

I just applied a lot of adjustments to an image and would like to transform them in a new action. How can I create an action from the history?

(I tried to go back to the first step in history and started to record; then I just clicked each one of the history steps in sequence. The action saved was a lot of "click next history"...)

I'm using Photoshop CS4. And I'm a complete beginner.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you just need to do it all over again and record it.

PS. If you're thinking actions you can't be a complete beginner :)

Comment: Let's say I'm a 60% beginner by now ;-) It's sad that Photoshop cannot create actions from history. Do everything again is boring and, depending on the number of steps, completely subject to errors :(

Answer (score 1):

Like @pax said, I'm afraid that you will have to re-do the adjustments to your image, but instead of creating an action, if these adjustments were actually **Adjustments** (form the Menu bar, ***Image > Adjustments***), you can do the adjustments as **Adjustment Layers** and put them into a folder in your layers palette. This way, in the future, you can just drag the folder from one PSD into another, and you'll also have the ability to tweak the adjustments down the road!

[Using adjustment layers](http://photoshoptips.net/2005/09/16/adjustment-layers/)

Comment: hmmmmm I'm gonna try it. Interesting. And in fact I do most of the adjustments using adjustment layers.